# Why were a whole bunch of users just awarded the Vox Populi badge on meta?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I've only cast three votes on meta this week, and yet I was just awarded the Vox Populi badge. I see there was a spate of awarding this particular badge, but I haven't noticed a spate of meta voting.

Comment: Let's get this to the main meta if it's not already there...

Comment: I got it too, but didn't vote.

Comment: @bmike there's no need to move this to MSO.  Here is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just deployed a change that affects the voting badges.  This is why you see a number of these badges being awarded.

For more information about this change, you can see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123048/140548).

Note that there was a bug with Vox Populi only that awarded too many of them (beyond the expected more for retroactive awards) and a fix has been deployed.  The erroneous awards have been cleaned up.

Comment: Woo and thanks. I haven't seen diamonds (other than our elected ones) here of late.  Glad to have a speedy response :-)